# Problemas con la versión de Angular 4 (HttpClient)

Tags: angular

Tengo problema para importar la librería HttpClient. Revisé la versión que tengo instalada y es Angular 6, ¿se puede hacer algo para 'rebajar' a Angular 4.3?

Espero sus respuestas.

Comment: Tenés que borrar toda la carpeta `node_modules`, actualizar la versión de angular en el `package.json` y correr `npm install`. Pero... Si pudieras reparar el problema para importar seria mejor, asi tendrás la versión actualzada. Cual es el error ?

Comment: Mi problema es que ni siquiera me deja poner "HttpClient", sólo me marca error y me dice "Quitar importación"

Comment: Estas haciendo la importación ??? (Ej. `import import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';`)

Comment: Sí, pero no me permite importarla, me marca un error. Como si le faltara ese componente.

Comment: En Angular 6 no hay problema con importar esa librería.... Seguramente te lo marca en gris porque la estás importando pero no la estas usando... Asegurate de usarlo en el constructor ( `constructor(private http: HttpCliente) ...`)

Comment: Gracias, voy a continuar programando y si eso es, creo que se resolverá el problema. Saludos.

Comment: Por cierto, me dejó de marcar en gris, pero me marca el siguiente error: "No se encuentra el módulo '@angular/common/http' "

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81375/discussion-between-nery-ortez-and-yarizza).

Answer (score 1):

Cómo la estás importando?

Para poder importarla, antes tienes que importar HttpClientModule en tu app.module.ts.

```
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Algo así puede servirte.

Luego ya puedes importar HttpClient, por ejemplo, en algún servicio, así:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Y más abajo en el mismo servicio algo similar a:

```
export abstract class ApiService<T>  {
    protected headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    protected httpClient: HttpClient;

    constructor(protected injector: Injector) {
        this.httpClient = injector.get(HttpClient);
    }
  //Todo el resto...
  //Ya podrías hacer métodos como este ejemplo:
      protected get(url, params=null)  {
        return this.httpClient.get(url + this.queryParams(params), { headers: this.headers })
                              .map((res: Response)  => { return res; })
                              .catch(err => { return this.handleErrors(err); });
  }
}
```

Comment: Intento consumir un webservice, y para ello necesito importar. Al momento de ponerla en el documento "import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';" sólo me marca en gris y me impide acceder.Investigué un poco y vi que es por la versión. Sólo tengo una duda, ¿angular 6 no debería permitirla, ya que es una versión superior a angular 4?

Answer (score 1):

Si compila bien tu codigo (ng serve // npm start), puede que sea un error de referencia en tu IDE, prueba cerrando y volviendo abrir tu IDE.

Siempre en cuando hayas referenciado en tu module.ts:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

y en tu ...component.ts

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
```

En caso contrario, copia el error que sale en tu browser para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Pudiste solucionar el problema, me pasa lo mismo cada vez que creo un proyecto de Angular no tengo la librerias de HttpClient.

Answer (score 0):

deveras declarar el httpmodule en el modulo principal [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

con eso ya podrás utilizar HTTPCLIENT

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]